# How to use RSA in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, rsa

I am coding a module which will use RSA to encode, decode and generate keys. But I have not found any API in kernel source(I mean linux-kernel/crpyto/) about RSA.

I don't want to take the OpenSSL, or something like it, into kernel because that will take so much time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [crypto modules](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/crypto.h?v=2.6.25.8) expose the [Linux Kernel Crypto API](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6451). RSA support is present in [kernel 3.7](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/crypto/asymmetric_keys). Though the implementation is [limited to signature verification](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.7#head-04b98580ad0a22b9dfb66cc1c6f7c744fdcd22a4).

**More information**

- [how to use CryptoAPI in the linux kernel 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869028/how-to-use-cryptoapi-in-the-linux-kernel-2-6)
- [Linux Crypto API and linux/crypto.h - Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152829/linux-crypto-api-and-linux-crypto-h-documentation)
- [Linux Cross Reference - crypto.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/crypto.h)

Comment: Sorry, but your link with text "crypto modules" and "Linux Cross Reference - crypto.h" is dead. Could you update it?